# NGXS subscribe for Select variable doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I'm using angular 11 with NGXS. I have a problem with a subscription for variable in state
I have this subscription:

```
@Select(state => state.alert.alerts)
alerts$: Observable<any[]>
ngOnInit(): void {
this.alerts$.subscribe(alerts => {
      if (alerts) {
        this.alertSubject.next(alerts[0])
      }
    })
}
```

and subscription doesn't work when the object is changing in the state

My state is:

```
@Action(AddAlertAction)
addAlert(ctx: StateContext<AlertStateModel>, { text, type }: AddAlertAction) {
    const alerts = ctx.getState().alerts
    alerts.push({ text, type })
    ctx.patchState({ alerts })
  }
```

and this state works properly but in function ngOnInit subscription doesn't work.
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

you should not use push prototype while updating a state slice unless you are not handling immutability manually. an alternative code block for immutability handled by ngxs itself might be as follows

```js
@Action(AddAlertAction)
addAlert({ patchState }: StateContext<AlertStateModel>, { text, type }: AddAlertAction) {
    const { alerts } = getState();
    
    patchState({ ...alerts, { text, type } });
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work. my and your solution successfully update state variable but then subscription in component doesn't work

Comment: if state slice is changing then subscription must be working. can you confirm it is not by adding a log to subscription callback function body. and by the way this will be always true when it is always an array
if (alerts) {